# Limit the characters of a variable?

Tags: string, batch-file, variables

I have many variables that will be called in a loop. I wanted, for example - To make the variable, when exceeding 30 characters, it would be cut to 30 characters and add 3 dots at the end.

> **Example:**
>
> ```
> set text = Hello world
> ```
>
> **Becomes:**
>
> `"Hello ..."`

That would help me a lot, however - If anyone can do something more advanced, for example when cutting some parts of characters, add the dots to the middle of the text.

> **Example:**
>
> `set text = Hello wooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooorld "`
>
> **Becomes:**
>
> `"Hello wo...orld"`

Comment: Never ever put spaces around the equal sign in a set command. They become part of the variable name / the content. For the syntax of variable substrings see http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html

Comment: What did you do to transform `Hello world` to `Hello ...` . Please show your work. And you specified 30 as the max length for the string and then showed a 15 chars string as the desired result: `Hello wo...orld`. It is not logical to reduce the length of say, a 31 chars string to 15 and at the same time keep the strings with ...,28,29,30 chars intact, you should reduce them to the maximum allowed length, but still you may prefer another length for the resulting strings, either way you should be specific about that, it can not be random. This can even help you to find the solution by yourself.

Comment: I'll provide an answer as soon as I've asked my crystal ball...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
call :convert Hello
call :convert Hello beautiful World
call :convert Hello wooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooorld
goto :eof

:convert
set "x=%*"
REM if the string is shorter than 10 chars, just print it and return:
if "%x:~10%" == "" echo %1 & goto :eof
REM else print first 7 chars, thee dots and the last three chars:
echo %x:~0,7%...%x:~-3%
```

Adapt the following numbers to your needs (you mentioned 30 chars, but none of your examples do match that number):
`10` for "first ten characters" (due to zero-based counting it checks, if there is anything in the *eleventh* position)
`7` for the number of characters before the three dots
`3` for the number of last characters

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your issue can be solved very easily using `%variable:~num_chars_to_skip%`

Using the `SET` command we can edit your variable and have it remove everything over `30` characters in length. From there we can take the new variable we made and manipulate it from there.

This code bellow will remove all characters exceeding 30 and display them in the `text...` format.

```
@ECHO OFF

::Edit string one with 30 char limit. String has 40 Chars.
SET String=0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
SET Result=%String:~0,30%
ECHO %Result%...

::Edit string one with 30 char limit. String has 90 Chars.
SET String=012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
SET Result=%String:~0,30%
ECHO %Result%...

::Edit string one with 30 char limit. String has 6 Chars.
SET String=0123456
SET Result=%String:~0,30%
ECHO %Result%...

PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
```

Learn more about syntax-substring here: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html